# want to send an email in symfony 2 with variable

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to send an email with a variable name. I have created the action as follow:

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('EnsNewBundle:Products')
            ->find(2);



        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('ucerturohit@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('ucerturohit@gmail.com')
        ->setContentType("text/html")
        ->setBody($this->renderView('EnsNewBundle:Default:index.html.twig'));
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->render('EnsNewBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('name'=>$product->getName()));
```

Here I want to transmit the data `$product->getName()` with the mail. In `index.html.twig` I have defined as follow:

```
Id of the product 5<br/>
Name of the product {{name}} <br/>
Description Fast Internet browsing speed
```

when I am executing this action then I am getting the error `undefined variable name in index.html.twig`. What should I do, if i want to set this value before sending the mail.
If I make hard code for email body then there is no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine's method `find()` should return collection of results, not a single object.

You should probably use `findOneByXXX()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have add just this thing and the problem is solved.

```
 ->setBody($this->renderView('EnsNewBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('name1'=>$product->getName())));
```